# Python : Map over multidimensional dictionary using a list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I need a function to change values within a nested dictionary, 
by crawling a list instead of the usual `dic[key1][key2] = value`

e.g :

```
IN[0]: dic = {'1': 23, '3': {'a': 'foo', 'b': 67}}
IN[1]: l = ['3', 'a']
IN[2]: func(dic, l , newvalue)
IN[3]: print dic
```

Expected output :

```
OUT[4]: dic = {'1': 23, '3': {'a': newvalue, 'b': 67}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us **to write the program** for you, suggestions, and external links are **off-topic**. Where is your specific question, what problem does your implementation face and where is your [mcve]?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I'm sorry but I'm not sure that you read the post, but the issue is quite clear and the example is trivial, what clarification you're asking for. instead of changing a value using `dic['3']['a']=newvalue` he want to use a list `['3','a']`

Comment: @PatrickArtner you are right - the OP must show the code they have tried to write which doesn’t work, explain what they expect it shoudl do and specifically why it doesn’t work. Expecting to be given code is off-topic here.

Comment: @barny but what if the OP didn't write a code because he didn't have any idea how to start, happens all the time, you have a problem and no idea how to fix it, he need a function that does a certain thing so he asks for help, isn't that what this website all about

Comment: @Ben This site is no "I need this code please" codegenerator - we do not answer these kind of questions. They are offtopic. He has to at least try to solve it and show what he tried so we can help him fix his code.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I know, I've been here long enough, but a little kindness and understanding that someone is stuck & may need a small help specially if he's asking just for couple of lines of code, isn't a bad thing

Comment: @Ben there is no "kindness" in providing solutions. You rob the asker of the experience of solving it themself, learnign in the process. You cripple his ability to tackle other, more complicated tasks by stealing an opportunity to grow solving a problem they have. Beside that - the question is _bad_ - there is no clear cut way for others with similar task to find it or use it to solve their problem. It has no clear "problem" and the title is not helpiung much either.

Comment: @Ben.Ayoub they shoud go find a tutorial and learn. But asking for code on here is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def func(dic, keys, value):
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        dic = dic.setdefault(key, {})
    dic[keys[-1]] = value

func(dic, l , newvalue)
print(dic)
```

This is not good to use unnecessary things like `exec` and `globals()`.

Comment: Bad move providing an answer when the OP didn’t make any effort. I hope you enjoy the reputation points you “gained”.

Comment: @barny There were several answers here. and conversation about below all. but they all deleted theirs.

Comment: @barny and also this will be helpful for you to read and understand, read `When should I vote down??` part carefully. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down